# WSGI-Python : Custom MySQL port has NO EFFECT on _mysql.connect

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

This is how i connect to MySQL via WSGI-Python

```
def a():
    b=_mysql.connect('localhost','1','','z',3333)
    return b
```

in other words i changed the MySQL port from 3306 to 3333
and then added it here.

but it turns out.. this has no effect what so ever.

even without a port number i can seem to be able to connect to MySQL just fine.

is it perhaps because it is "localhost" ?

but what is even more.. when i place a wrong port number there..

it has no effect what so ever.

can this also be due to because it is a localhost ?

**UPDATE**

i changed

```
localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1
```

it seems to have effect now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this line is in your hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

and is not commented out.